# How to add more than 10 text parameters per app

Tags: ios, firebase

Is there any way to add more than 10 text or 40 numeric parameters per app?

I see "You may use up to 10 text parameters and 40 numeric parameters per

app." when i add some parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Only way is to use google DB(BigQuery).

By asking google support team.